# How to use ember-data canary with ember-cli 2.3.0-beta.1

Tags: ember-data, ember-cli

[ember-cli 2.2.0-beta.1](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.2.0-beta.1) moved ember-data out of `bower.json` and into `package.json` handled by npm. How do I specify I want to use the canary version of ember-data in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [git url dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies) feature of `package.json`. It should look something like:

```
// package.json
...
"devDependencies": {
  "ember-data": "emberjs/data#master"
}
```